# how to select img with jquery on an html page that's not yours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display an html page in a div, and then select all the img tags in that page individually and get them to display an overlay div on the images.

So far I can put the html inside a div called "asd", and the jquery seems to work with the img tags that are external to the html page, but the selector doesn't select the img tags inside the div "asd" itself.

I have tried using an iframe but I read somewhere that jquery doesn't work inside iframes because selecting an iframe even if it has an ID tag doesn't work. If it can be used using an iframe please let me know.

So far I've tried $("object img"), $("body img") and $("img") without luck. The google search is simply "electric cars" images.

My jquery selector wraps the img tag in a div, and then inserts a button with absolute position inside the div so that the button will appear in the top right corner of every img.

Code:

```
<div id="asd">

</div>

<button class="buttons_move_shift_min_max_close" onclick="selector()" style="position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;z-index:100;">button</button>

<script>

$("#asd").html('<object data="https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=electric+cars&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMqcHZvcPeAhXHtI8KHUkZDRsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=897" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>');

function selector()
{
     $("img").each
      (
         function()
         {
             $(this).wrap("<div id=\"wrapp\" class=\"wrapp\" style=\"margin:0;padding:0;\"></div>");    
         }
     );
      $(".wrapp").append("<button class=\"hybrid\" style=\"z-index:100;position:absolute;\"></button>");
}

</script>
```

I have also tried waiting until the page has fully loaded the img tags with no avail. If this can be achieved with simple javascript do tell.

I know trying to run jquery on html that's not yours is tricky and probably looks like a silly idea but there must be a way without having to create a custom chrome plugin app.

Comment: You can fork my project https://github.com/Subterrane/nutsacker-extension and modify it.

Comment: That's what I was looking at doing initially, but I want a project that can't easily be copied by fb. If I can't just select the img tag I may have to create my own browser in android lol. Great project btw. Had a good laugh.

Comment: I was thinking, there's a script that says "noscript" in the google image search page. Is this or is there code like it that prevents other javascript from being run in the page? If so, I could avoid that script with a simple str_replace on the object before displaying.

Comment: I think what you want to do is fetch the page with AJAX, but instead of adding it to a `div` or an `iframe`, feed it to the [DOM Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). Then you can select the image elements and manipulate them before placing the results in your page.

Comment: Oh ok. How to do that? I know ajax can execute a php page but I wouldn't know how to fetch a page, parse it to the DOM and manipulate it, and then somehow send it to a div??

Comment: Looks like CORS is blocking it. I guess you would need to do it on a server.

Comment: I have wamp and am doing it from a localhost webpage if that's what you mean. How is CORS blocking it? Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: There is a workaround .You can use a proxy server.

Comment: and use curl in php?

Answer (score 0):

**Cross Origin Proxy Server**

The gist of it is that you have your webpage that asks a server for some data. That server asks ANOTHER server for the data and passes the result back to the webpage.

Here is an example server: [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com)

Here is a succinct explanation from [crossorigin.me](https://corsproxy.github.io)

> A CORS proxy is a service that allows developers (probably you) to access resources from other websites, without having to own that website.

These servers come with a few caveats and ultimately, you would want to create your own.

```js
function go() {
  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=electric+cars')
    .then(res => {
      return res.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
      document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = data;
    }).catch(err => {
      document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = err.message;
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```